# Rails - How to remove vue.js with webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

I installed Vue.js with the command line:

> ```
> bundle exec rails webpacker:install:vue
> ```

How can revert it and uninstall Vue.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webpacker` v5 currently doesn't have uninstall support, so you'd have to manually undo the [`install:vue` command's actions](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb):

1. **Remove vue loader from config/webpack/loaders**: [Delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L3-L4) `<rootDir>/config/webpack/loaders/vue.js`
2. **Remove vue loader**: In `<rootDir>/config/webpack/environment.js`:

   a. [delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L6-L9) `const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')`

   b. [delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L11-L13) `environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new  VueLoaderPlugin())`

   c. [delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L15-L18) `const vue = require('./loaders/vue')`

   d. [delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L20-L22) `environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)`
3. **Remove `.vue` file extension support from Webpack config**: In the Webpacker config file, [delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L24-L25) `- .vue`
4. **Remove example entry file**: [Delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L27-L29) `<srcDir>/hello_vue.js`
5. **Remove Vue app file**: [Delete](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L31-L33) `<srcDir>/app.vue`
6. **Uninstall Vue dependencies**: From `<rootDir>`, [run](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/741b314/lib/install/vue.rb#L35-L38) `yarn remove vue vue-loader vue-template-compiler`